# why the rxswift run only 1 times

Tags: rx-swift

```
Observable.of("A", "B", "C").subscribe{  print("test", $0)  } // run 4 times
```

--- output:

> test next(A) test next(B) test next(C) test completed

but the code:  why run only 1  times

```
  Observable.of("A", "B", "C").subscribe{   print("test")   }
```

--- output

> test

Comment: are you using playground to test?

Comment: When i test this i get expected result. Are you trying in playground?